# Better way of storing "messages" data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm building a website that has a user messaging system. I'm using MySQL to store every data. The inbox **table** is set up like this:

```
  `mid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `to_uid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `from_uid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `content` TEXT(4000) NOT NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `isvisible` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
```

I had the user-to-user messaging set up to use only characters and numbers so that's fine. What I'm trying to do are notification messages to the user. What's a good way to insert messages if they contain php variables and html? Here's where I am so far before inserting it.

```
$content = "".$username." is requesting to join your trip. Click <a href=\"browse.php?tid=D".$t_tid."\">here</a> to go to the trip.<button>here\'s a button</button>";
```

Is this the proper way? I'm just a beginner so anyone who could shed some light is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not know if this helps, but you can prevent messages from containing any html.  They can be htmlentities'd out so they appear as regular characters.

Comment: Keeping PHP variables means you are putting PHP codes inside. Is it some kind of CMS?

Comment: @Shiplu Nothing like that. I just want it to be stored as something like `mike is requesting to join your trip. Click <a href="browse.php?tid=D8">here</a> to go to the trip.<button type="button">here's a button</button>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a column like this

```
`message_type` enum ('REQ_JOIN_GROUP', 'REQ_FRINDSHIP', 'REQ_TAG_APPROVE', 'MSG_PRIV', 'MSG_WALL', 'TAG_PHOTO', 'TAG_NOTE')
`message_param` varchar(20)
```

Depending on the message type you can just create the message.
For example.

1. REQ_JOIN_GROUP:
   from_uid has requested to_uid to join group message_param
2. REQ_FRIENDSHIP:
   from_uid has requested to make friendship with to_uid(you)
3. REQ_TAG_APPROVE:
   from_uid has tagged to_uid(you) in message_param photo

Just normalize it.

Comment: Yes. Don't store the HTML, store the data you need to generate it.

Comment: I wasn't trying to store it actually. I was just trying to keep things organized so I could insert them later on via .. VALUES ('$from_uid', '$to_uid', '$subject', '$content') ..

Comment: If you normalize, it'll be organized. You can insert data later. But it will be more efficient and more benefits.